# Accepting Nominations — Who should Moderate♦ this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally, Moderators♦ are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we **need to appoint THREE provisional Moderators** to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="https://eosio.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://eosio.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="https://eosio.meta.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://eosio.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: This is a list of all not declined nominations (not containing "decline"): https://eosio.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A15+is%3Aa+-decline

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Leo Ribeiro would be a good choice because:

- No-one else in the top ten highest reputations have cast more than 100 votes. Leo has cast 155.
- Leo has answered a staggering 30 questions.
- Leo has asked 8 positively received questions.
- Leo is an active commenter, with 41 comments.
- Leo has made 13 revisions and has 6 post edits. This shows commitment to ensuring the content here is of high quality.
- They have visited every day so far, currently 23/30 on their way to the enthusiast badge.
- Highest reputation. Not enough reason on its own, but combined with above...

Comment: I'm also behind Leo as a moderator, trustworthy guy!

Comment: Also behind Leo he has contributed an open-source EOS dapp already https://busy.org/@leordev/monstereos-creating-your-first-monster-in-eos-jungle-testnet

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I would love to help this community.

- Currently I am writing my computer science master thesis about blockchain and especially EOS
- Several times a day I check the EOS stack exchange site and anwser or comment what I can
- I am an active developer and have several years of working experience including several programming languages and frameworks (C++, NodeJS, React, Docker)
- Also I am working on a translation for the EOS whitepaper to the German language
- Furthermore I am a crypto enthusiast and checking the news regualary, therefore I would love to grow and maintain an open/vivid community

Feel free to ask me some personal questions.

Answer (score 3):

[image] 

[image]

#### Notes:

I'll self nominate.

I'm not a block-producer and will never run as one, just an avid EOS community supporter with no financial or political motivations. I'm fairly active on this stack exchange and the [/r/eos subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/eos/) (I won the sub design contest, username: [/u/altShiftDev](https://www.reddit.com/user/altShiftDev)). Currently working on the redesign now along with Charles from EOS 42. Generally I just want to give back to the crypto community as it has given me so much.

I'm a full time senior designer & front-end developer, I'm currently working on a crypto tracker & portfolio app called Coinster.

Comment: @RobertCartaino your right that the community is in need of moderation if you can't even abide your own code from the theory of moderation you linked above. If my original post was somehow offensive to the community then it was up to the community to not vote me in, not for you to censor it.

Comment: Promotional content is removed, not voted on.  Please do not continue with this product promotion. It is not appropriate here nor on the site.

Comment: @RobertCartaino it's not product promotion it's establishing my credibility as a community supporter. The users deserve to know why they're voting for and I'm allowed to state my case. As I said multiple times I have no financial stake, the app contains neither ads nor methods for monetization, by continuing to censor my posts and remove mention that there's no ads - nor money involved - you're creating a false air of promotion. Your ineptitude and power tripping are the exact reasons I'm self-nominating. You may be director of comms for SX but it doesn't change the fact that you're wrong.

Comment: Monetization is not the issue. It's fine when you state that you are a full time developer with the name of the app (which I left as it establishes credibility, like you said), but when it goes on to discuss the benefits of the app and it's free and how to get it with links to download etc, that is beyond what is necessary and appropriate in this context. I should also note that watching someone go straight to the name-calling in comments and flags over a routine good-faith edit is generally a big red flag for us to pass on appointing them as a moderator.

Comment: I get that you believe your edit was a 'routine good-faith edit' but I suggest you have a look at this wonderful [article](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). Firstly, no edit is in good faith when altering a candidate's self-representation. You're not editing an answer to a coding question, you're deliberately altering the representation of the candidate to the community. I'm sorry that calling you inept hurt your feelings, I suggest thicker skin if you choose to remain inept in your duties. Inept moderation is a red flag of mine & so is hypocrisy.

Comment: @altShiftDev: I jumping in as another community manager from the company to handle flags. To get back to the core issue, I followed the link to your app and it doesn't seem to do anything. (Just a spinner.) So it really doesn't add much to your candidacy. Ultimately the important thing to consider in a moderator is how they interact with the community. That's why the Reddit links haven't been removed.

Comment: @JonEricson you probably have javascript disabled but that's beside the point entirely.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

#### Self Nomination

Huge fan of EOS and Dan Larimer, I've found I've learn much more about Stack Exchange in general on this site.

I'd like to really make this place a great place to go to really understand the concepts behind EOS and get people developing as soon as they can and helping awareness and understanding of the network in general.

The integrity of the site means a lot to me and I think this experience will be of great benefit to my career.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Nominating myself as well.

When it comes to stackexchange I care about: **docs, grammar, manners, norms, formatting and presentation.**

I'll aim to moderate in a manner that both **encourages new users to participate** and engage, but that **also discourages low level questions**.

I get the sense that many users are posting artificial questions in the vain hope of getting an upvote and gaining some reputation. I sympathize and would look for ways to encourage new users to think about real questions that add value. This is best done through thoughtful comments, feedback, and interaction.

Allowing questions with 0 upvotes and 0 answers to linger on for days and weeks, unchanged and without any moderation brings the quality of the whole site down (and everything is on a case by case basis of course, we do have many valid 0votes/0answer questions which I think will get more engagement as more features get fleshed out in EOS).

Professionally I am a dev, I plan to transition full time into EOS this year.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

I'm a developer and a Stack Exchange power-user.

I've had periods where I've been very active on:

- Stack Overflow
- Unix & Linux
- Ask Ubuntu

---

[image]

For the last 3-4 months I've been much less active. Reason being I discovered Steemit.com.

I had made an account almost a year prior but never used it. At that time I was more interested in Monero and Ethereum. I signed up but never really looked into the system behind steem.

Since I've been getting into it recently I became extremely interested. I have made modest code contributions to several popular applications on Steemit including steemit.com and busy.org.

---

I started listening to all the videos in which Dan explained the ideas behind Steemit. When I discovered he left Steem to create EOS, naturally I became very interested in EOS.

I'm now invested in EOS and have my tokens registered.

I'm providing some commentary on EOS developments on [my Steem blog](http://busy.org/@kirkins).

I'm willing to provide some moderation for the site as someone familiar with the platform and interested in EOS.

*Bonus: I made the first post on the meta for this site.*